# Cannot find user-defined function in function calling stored procedure

Tags: sql, ssms, sql-function

I am new to SQL, so I am probably making a very simple mistake, and am hoping that someone can point out what it is.

I have the following existing stored procedure that generates a new primary key (I know there is an automatic way to do this, but we want to handle generation on our own):

```
ALTER   PROCEDURE [dbo].[newid] @tablename AS CHAR(10), @fieldname AS CHAR(15) = '', @ioffset AS INT, @theID as int = 0 output 
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON

 DECLARE @value AS INT
 IF @ioffset < 1 SET @ioffset = 1
 IF LEN(@fieldname) > 0
  BEGIN
    UPDATE id SET @value = CONVERT(INT,cvalue)+@ioffset-1, cvalue = CONVERT(CHAR,(CONVERT(INT,cvalue)+@ioffset)) WHERE UPPER(ctablename) = UPPER(@tablename) AND UPPER(cfieldname) = UPPER(@fieldname)
   SELECT @value
  END
 ELSE
  BEGIN
   UPDATE id SET @value = CONVERT(INT,cvalue)+@ioffset-1, cvalue = CONVERT(CHAR,(CONVERT(INT,cvalue)+@ioffset)) WHERE UPPER(ctablename) = UPPER(@tablename)
   SELECT @value 
  End
 SET NOCOUNT OFF
set @theID = @value
END
```

I need to call this from a select statement, so I had to make a shell function that would call it. I created the following scalar-valued function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetNextID]
(   
    @tablename AS CHAR(10),
    @fieldname AS CHAR(15) = '',
    @ioffset AS INT 
)
RETURNS int 
AS
    BEGIN 
        RETURN dbo.newid(@tablename, @fieldname, @ioffset)
    END
```

I am now trying to test this, using the following:

```
DECLARE @ret int
EXEC @ret = dbo.GetNextID 'Client','iclientid',1
PRINT @ret
```

I get the error:

> Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.newid", or the name is ambiguous.

As I said, I am new to SQL and I am sure that there is something very simple that I am missing.

**SOLUTION**

Since you cannot access a Stored Procedure from a Function, I decided to argue the case for allowing auto-increment. Since this was a one time conversion to an in-house database, setting up the table to allow it, and then changing it after the data has been transferred seemed to be the best way to handle it.

Comment: Its a function, so call it as  `SELECT GetNextID('Client','iclientid',1)` to execute...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call stored procedure in functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for executing the function

```
DECLARE @ret int
SET @ret = (SELECT dbo.GetNextID ('Client','iclientid',1))
PRINT @ret
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this gives me the same error. If I remove dbo, I get a different error about 'GetNextID' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: As @Gatej has suggested it is not appropriate to call a stored proc form a function. Why don't you call the proc directly. You can exec the proc as `DECLARE @id int; EXEC dbo.newid 'Client','iclientid', 1, @id OUTPUT`. Then select `@id`.

Comment: @user2989408: I cannot call the stored procedure directly because I am using it to create new primary keys while copying multiple rows of data from one table to another. I need the function in the select statement to map to the primary key. I know this would be easier if we just allowed SQL to auto-update the primary key, but that is not the way management wants to go.